# create a relation between two models in third

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to development, and I'm at a dead end.
I'm trying to create a grant system for Python3 and Django

I have models:

```py
class Grant(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    program = models.ForeignKey('Program',   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter name of the grant")
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'),verbose_name="Total budget")
    grantee = models.ForeignKey('Grantee', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grant_name = models.ForeignKey('Grant', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    CAT_LIST = (
    ('s', 'Salary'),
    ('e', 'Event'),
    ('t', 'Transportation'),
    ('p', 'Printing'),
    ('eq', 'Equipment'),
    ('of', 'Office'),
    ('o', 'Other')
    )
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CAT_LIST, blank=True)
    spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    repbudget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'),verbose_name="Budget")
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True)
    # Below the mandatory fields for generic relation
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

class Installment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    grant_name = models.ForeignKey('Grant', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    date_report = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Now I need to create a model for Installment Report, and it should include Installment and Report’s categories for the same Grant. 
Something like this:

```py
class InstallmentReport(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title =  models.ForeignKey('Report', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    installment = models.ForeignKey('Installment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I create this report, I can connect with `Installment`, but I can’t image how to filter the Report’s title for same Grant.
Could you give some advice or maybe some example?

P.S. I apologize for my mistakes in English and possibly in the design of the code

Comment: Please mention the version of Django you used as well. There are some syntax differences in different Django versions (ForeignKey relating statements, URL patterns  etc.).

Comment: I'm using Python3.7.3 and Django 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do it through a view template, using POST, for it, I need to add to Report's model Installment. Then `{% for categorie in installment.report %}`. But will be fine, if I can do it in create or update view. But I didn't come how to filter report categories, without it, a user should select from all categories from all grant, but it is not a variant.